# Is it possible to convert hair to alpha planes?

Tags: particles, hair

In Zbrush you can groom your hair, and then convert that to alpha planes. I'm curious if it's possible to achieve the same result in Blender?

I tag particles because that seems to be what people in other communities recommended. I've checked a few video using particle system for grass but I can't find anything related to grooming or direction controlling.

An example of what I wanted to do is this little guy here. The planes need to follow different directions in different area. Such as spreading out from the eye following the edge loops.

https://www.artstation.com/artwork/56wLO

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Particle edit & Render as Object

Blender has some [nice tools](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/mode.html) to work with hairs.

To assign planes to hairs, use the Object (or Group) option you can find in the *Render* panel of the particle system.

Texture the plane and all the particles will follow that.

You can comb hair particles in the particle *Edit Mode*.

[image]

Once satisfied, you can run the "[Make duplicates real](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html#make-duplicate-real)" operator to convert the particles to individual meshes so you'll be able to export the objects fbx, obj... and use them in other softwares.

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks for recording! I noticed you're in particle mode whille grooming, does that mean hair is considered particle system?

Comment: Yes, it's still a hair particle. The plane is an overlay. Till you keep the particle system, you can interactively groom the hairs. You can "bake" the hairs if you would like to abandon the particles workflow. I've edited the question in this sense.